# Redux Toolkit Query polling is causing re-renders for each fetching

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Data is not changing but re-render of component is happening on each fetch.
I've done some research and found out info about selectFromResult property, to access only data itself and not isFetching prop or others

Here is my query from apiSlice:

```
getNotification: builder.query<GetNotificationsResponse, GetNotificationsRequest>({
      query: ({ page, limit }) => ({
        url: `notifications?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`,
        method: 'GET',
      }),
    }),
```

Here is how Im using polling and selectFromResult

```
  const result = useGetNotificationQuery(
    {
      page: 1,
      limit: 10,
    },
    {
      pollingInterval: 1000,
      selectFromResult: data => data.data,
    },
  );
```

Comment: const {data, isLoading, isError, error} = useGetNotificationQuery(..

Comment: Is more general approach, not sure you want isFetching tho, isLoading will trigger only if there is no data, isFetching would trigger on each poll

Answer (score 0):

Note that a shallow equality check is performed on the overall return value of selectFromResult to determine whether to force a rerender. i.e. it will trigger a rerender if any of the returned object values change reference. If a new array/object is created and used as a return value within the callback, it will hinder the performance benefits due to being identified as a new item each time the callback is run. When intentionally providing an empty array/object, in order to avoid re-creating it each time the callback runs, you can declare an empty array/object outside of the component in order to maintain a stable reference.

i think this [link](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#selecting-values-from-results) would help you out.

to avoid unnecessary re-renders, we need to ensure that whatever data we extract is memoized correctly. To do this, we should create a new selector instance that the component can reuse every time it renders so that the selector memoizes the result.

Comment: Here they are using selectFromResult in slightly different way (I guess in way it should be actually used) - to select the part of data that is returned from query.

Comment: What I want is to avoid re-renders if data is not changed, Im getting notifications array from back and I should constantly poll it to see if there are new notifications, but I don't want the re-render if the data is not changed.

Comment: I update the link with sample code example